# Caravel built wrong sql for Mysql?

Tags: mysql, apache-superset

Caravel generate some sql like `DATE("createTime")` which always return a null, because "createTime" is a string, not a field name for Mysql. I think it should be `DATE(createTime)`, any advise? Is there a config switch to handle this, in Caravel or in Mysql?

Comment: Are you sure it's not an [ANSI quoted string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes)?

Comment: @jpmc26 you are right, I should set sql mode  ANSI_QUOTES. But I have no permission to set global variable. Is there any way to set sql_mode at session level via connection url? Or is there any way to change sql template to generate sql without quotes?